# How do I unlock a remotely locked laptop if forgotten password

Tags: security, passwords, windows-11

I remotely locked my Windows 11 laptop using my Microsoft Account to see how MS stood up against Apple, forgetting that I had changed both the Administrator’s password & PIN which I can’t recall.  I may have switched it to a Local Account at some point, as there’s no option to reset the password through Microsoft.

I had always used my fingerprint to log in, but might have changed that also, as it no longer works either (or may have stopped working after unsuccessfully trying several times using the same finger in succession, as now it says “Your PIN is required to sign in” whenever I use any of my fingers).

I’ve tried:

- Creating a new Administrator User on Elevated Command Prompt via Win11 Installation Media (net localgroup administrator (User) /add)—which failed to create any users;
- Logging into Safe Mode—which still required the password;
- Accessing the Advanced Startup environment—which was basically irrelevant;
- Clicking on “I forgot my PIN”—which literally did nothing (screen blanked out then returned to the sign in page);
- Numerous 3rd-party password-recovery programs—which all failed to run on the affected computer.
- Searched countless hours on how to remove/bypass Administrator’s password to log in in order to remove/change the password but couldn’t find any solutions.

I hadn’t yet created a Password Reset Disk nor set up any security questions (recently got the laptop and had just transferred everything from the old one—which I had WIPED), and there isn’t another Administrator on this PC that I can use to unlock the computer.

Any suggestions, other than resorting to re-installing Windows and losing everything, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you remotely release it by the same method you locked it? That's how Apple's Find My structure works.

Comment: Try using Safe Mode.   Boot into the Safe Mode with cmd enabled. To do this, restart your PC and press the F8 button and then choose the option “Safe Mode with Command Prompt” to boot into the OS.   
Run command prompt and type in the command: net user username newpassword and hit enter.
Next,  enter your account and type in a new password.
Finally, restart your PC, and hopefully the password has changed

Comment: You may be able to boot with a Windows bootable USB key and copy documents, email and so on to a USB Drive.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions—Unfortunately, there’s only option to LOCK the computer, not release; Safe Mode still requires the password to log in; and Windows boots up fine, it just requires the User’s password, which I can’t remember…

Comment: Unfortunately there's no magical solution for that.

Comment: You need to collect documents (locally) as I suggested and re-install Windows

Comment: If you were using the built-in Administrator account, and you forgot the password to that account, there really isn't a solution to your problem. The built-in Administrator account was disabled by default, and can be enabled, without Administrator permissions. So are you positive you enabled that account, set a password to that account, and then forgot the password to that account?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion John.  Is there a way to recover the documents if I’m locked out and don’t have a USB key, as I don’t have any other user that can access the files?